How to apply type safety in Prisma conditional select queries when dynamically constructing select object
I am using Prisma ORM in a TypeScript project and having trouble ensuring type safety when constructing a dynamic select query with conditional fields. Here’s the scenario:
I have a dynamic select object where fields are conditionally added based on certain parameters like email or skills. Here’s an example of the code:
const selectedFields: any = {
            employee_id: true,
            employee_name: true,
            employee_status: true,
            join_date: true,
            exit_date: true,
          };

   

     if(email) {
       selectedFields.employee_email:true;
      }

     if(skills){
       selectedFields.skills = {
        where : {
           skill_id: { in: skills}
         },
        select: {
          skill_name:true,
          tag:true,
        }
    }

 

   const employeeData = await prisma.employee.findMany({
       select: selectedFields 
    })

The issue is that by using any for selectedFields, I lose Prisma’s type safety and autocompletion. I tried to apply Prisma's generated type, such as Prisma.EmployeeSelect, but it expects all fields to be either true or false for simple boolean selects, and it doesn’t work with conditional logic for nested objects like skills.
Here’s the interface I want to ensure type safety against:
interface IEmployeeResponse {
  employee_id:string;
  employee_name: string;
  employee_status:string;
  join_date: Date;
  exit_date:Date;
  role:IRole;
  skills?: ISkills;
}

I want to dynamically build the select object while maintaining full type safety and autocompletion, especially when the skills field involves a nested object with conditional selection. How can I achieve type safety in this scenario with Prisma's select object?
